# Changing how a variable is declared based on the size of the worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very long and clunky code that works , but often crashes and gives a No Response message. One way of getting around this, I've found, is to declare variables as Integers, rather than Long Integers if I know they won't exceed 32,767.

To ensure that I won't run into problems later on, I want to insert a line of code into the start of the script that will Dim the variables as either Integers or Long Integers depending on the size of the worksheet. What I have so far is:

```
 If Library.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row > 30000 Then
 Dim i As Long 
 Dim LastRow As Long 
 ElseIf Library.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row <= 30000  Then
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim LastRow As Integer
```

But this is giving me an error for having duplicate declaration statements. Is there another approach to this? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is your code doing!? There is something fundamentally wrong going on if using a bit less memory on a couple of variables is causing it to be unresponsive!

Comment: Also, [VBA converts all Integers to Long Integers anyway](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164754.aspx) - so you wouldn't actually see any performance benefit from this. If anything, using a `Long` is _more_ efficient because the value isn't being cast.

Comment: Ah OK, good point. It works to copy and paste a lot of information, re-arranging it based on a series of IF THEN statements. It works perfectly with small datasets, but stalls out sometimes on larger ones (though often still works).

Comment: Try putting the data into an array and work with it in memory instead. If your code is actually working then you can paste it to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get critique and optimisation tips

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a variant instead,

this will demonstrate

```
Dim a As Variant

a = 100
Debug.Print TypeName(a)

a = 10000000
Debug.Print TypeName(a)
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to how this is having a material effect on OP. However, if you want to use as little memory as possible you surely wouldn't want to declare as Variant.

Comment: I wasn't using as a solution to his memory issues, I was showing that it can be done for him, and its the best place to show/format code.  I personally wouldn't use that method, apologies if confusion caused.